# Type of singularity for $\tan(z)$ at $z = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = \tan(z)$. I want to know what happens at $z=\frac{\pi}{2}$. More specifically, I want to know what type of singularity it is. I suspect it to be a pole of order $1$, but how do I show this? Do I write out the Laurent series of $\tan(z)$ and just observe? Or should I look at $\lim (z - \frac{\pi}{2})\tan(z)$?

Comment: I would look at $$\lim_{z\to\pi/2}\frac{z-\frac\pi2}{\cot(z)}$$

Comment: Both approaches should work. You have an essential singularity, if the Laurent series contains infinite many terms with negative exponents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One has
$$\tan z={\sin z\over\cos z}=-{\cos(z-{\pi\over2})\over\sin(z-{\pi\over2})}={1\over z-{\pi\over2}}\left(- {z-{\pi\over2}\over\sin(z-{\pi\over2})}\cdot\cos(z-{\textstyle{\pi\over2}})\right)\ .$$
Here the large parenthesis on the right is analytic in a punctured neighborhood $\dot U$ of $z={\pi\over2}$ and has the limit $-1$ when $z\to{\pi\over2}$. Therefore it is in fact analytic in all of of $U$.

The conclusion is that $\tan$ has a simple pole at ${\pi\over2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $g(z)=1/f(z)=cotz$. As $g(π/2)=0$ but $g'(π/2)=-cosec^2(π/2)=-1\neq 0$, hence $g(z)$ has a simple zero at $z=π/2$ which implies that $f(z)$ has simple.....

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_{0}}(z-z_{0})^kf(z)\neq 0 $
and
$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_{0}}(z-z_{0})^{k+1}f(z)\neq 0 $, then $f(z)$ has a pole of order $k$ at the isolated singularity $z_{0}$.
You can easily see that for $k=1$, that is the case, as the first limit is equal to $-1$  and the second limit equals zero.